# How can we run amd64 architecture on a raspberry pi 4?

Tags: apt, 64-bit, raspberrypi, arm64

We are trying to install jevois-inventor onto the ubuntu18.04 but we flashed the ubuntu18.04 onto a raspberry pi 4 which is an arm64 architecture(we think). We tried to install amd64 packages individually on ubuntu terminal, but we can not install build-essential, gcc, etc packages for amd64.(We are new to Ubuntu and raspberry pi)

Comment: "How can we run amd64 architecture on a raspberry pi 4?" Replace the processor.

Comment: Add a second processor maybe  (your existing processor will see *amd64* code as data and not valid instructions), your alternative is a via interpreter, but it'd be *very very* slow.

Comment: @guiverc how do we add a second processor?

Comment: Currently none are available, I suspect their won't be any (*too small a market for a company to make that sort of addon and make money*), but in theory it's possible like apple IIs could use Z80 via addon, s100 bus computers could....

Comment: Question about "We tried to install amd64 packages" Why? Ubuntu provides arm. Why not use arm.

Answer (score 4):

You can't.

It's a completely different CPU, and there's no way you will be able to run stuff built for AMD64 on an ARM CPU.

The solution is, of course, to install packages for the correct architecture. Ubuntu (and Debian) handles multiple architectures just fine, by defining architecture in packages.

All of the toolchain (e.g. GNU GCC, assembler and so forth) is available for ARM, so it should be no problem to install the correct version.