# how to install libpng in a rapberry pi 4 which is running ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, raspberrypi

I was using this command to get the `libpng` files on my Raspberry Pi 4:

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libp/libpng/libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb
```

But I got an error after extracting the file saying that package architecture (amd64) does not match system (arm64).

Comment: The error message is correct, the architecture of your download (amd64) does **not** match the architecture of the pi; ie. a pi processor cannot run or use it.

Comment: Why are you manually downloading deb files in the first place? Why not use `apt`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can we run amd64 architecture on a raspberry pi 4?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1210404/how-can-we-run-amd64-architecture-on-a-raspberry-pi-4)

Answer (score 1):

Why did you pick the amd64 version to install?

Please [pick](https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/16.04/ubuntu-main-arm64/libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1_arm64.deb.html) a [arm64 version](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/arm64/libpng12-0) and install that.

Comment: I was trying to install tonido cloud server in a Raspberry pi. I follwed this link to install it https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-install-the-tonido-personal-cloud-server-on-ubuntu-server-18-04/