# Unable to install Oracle Virtualbox 6.1.16 in Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: virtualbox, oracle

'm new to Ubuntu OS and have recently installed Ubuntu 20.10 in my new Raspberry pi 4. /Objective is to install Virtual Oraclebox 6.1.16 (which has a release for Ubuntu 19.10/20.04). I'm getting error message "Unable to install Virtualbox 6.1 -The following packages have unmet dependencies". I'm not sure if I have to wait for Oracle to release a version for Ubuntu 20.10 or is there any other problem with the software (like any dependencies, etc.)?[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcV3C.png)

Comment: You haven't said what architecture you are using, but it'll be either `armv7` or `arm64`, where virtualbox is only available for `amd64`  (note the amd64 in the filename of your picture!)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can we run amd64 architecture on a raspberry pi 4?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1210404/how-can-we-run-amd64-architecture-on-a-raspberry-pi-4)

Comment: I would stick to the default repositories myself, eg. `6.1.14-dfsg-4` is currently available for *groovy* (19.10), but it'll upgrade to `6.1.16-dfsg-4~ubuntu1.20.10.1` the moment testing has been completed (currently it's in -proposed).  You'll need to be using an compatible *architecture* though to use it.

Answer (score 1):

The Raspberry Pi 4 is an ARM-based system. The package you’re installing is for x64-based systems, so will never work. If you want to do virtualization on the Pi, you *may* be able to use QEMU, but expect it to run poorly.