# Unable to install mysql 5.6 on ubuntu-server 20.04

Tags: server, 20.04, mysql

I'm raspberry pie 4B. I brush it as Ubuntu server 20.04 LTS

I try to search mysql5.7 with the following command

```
sudo apt-cache policy mysql-server
```

It gives me:

```
mysql-server:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1
  Version table:
     8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 500
        500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/main arm64 Packages
        500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security/main arm64 Packages
     8.0.19-0ubuntu5 500
        500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/main arm64 Packages
```

and I try downloaded the last version of MySql 5.6 that is available for Debian (and Ubuntu also)

```
wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQL-5.6/mysql-server_5.6.48-1debian9_amd64.deb-bundle.tar

dpkg -i mysql-server_5.6.48-1debian9_amd64.deb-bundle.tar

mysql apt update

sudo add-apt-repository 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty universe'

sudo apt-get update

apt-get install mysql-common-5.6 mysql-client-5.6 mysql-server-5.6
```

giver me:

```
dpkg: error processing archive libmysqlclient-dev_5.6.48-1debian9_amd64.deb (--install):
 package architecture (amd64) does not match system (arm64)
dpkg: error processing archive libmysqlclient18_5.6.48-1debian9_amd64.deb (--install):
 package architecture (amd64) does not match system (arm64)
dpkg: error processing archive libmysqld-dev_5.6.48-1debian9_amd64.deb (--install):
 package architecture (amd64) does not match system (arm64)
dpkg: error processing archive mysql-client_5.6.48-1debian9_amd64.deb (--install):
 package architecture (amd64) does not match system (arm64)
dpkg: error processing archive mysql-common_5.6.48-1debian9_amd64.deb (--install):
 package architecture (amd64) does not match system (arm64)
dpkg: error processing archive mysql-community-bench_5.6.48-1debian9_amd64.deb (--install):
 package architecture (amd64) does not match system (arm64)
dpkg: error processing archive mysql-community-client_5.6.48-1debian9_amd64.deb (--install):
 package architecture (amd64) does not match system (arm64)
dpkg: error processing archive mysql-community-server_5.6.48-1debian9_amd64.deb (--install):
 package architecture (amd64) does not match system (arm64)
dpkg: error processing archive mysql-community-source_5.6.48-1debian9_amd64.deb (--install):
 package architecture (amd64) does not match system (arm64)
dpkg: error processing archive mysql-community-test_5.6.48-1debian9_amd64.deb (--install):
 package architecture (amd64) does not match system (arm64)
dpkg: error processing archive mysql-server_5.6.48-1debian9_amd64.deb (--install):
 package architecture (amd64) does not match system (arm64)
dpkg: error processing archive mysql-testsuite_5.6.48-1debian9_amd64.deb (--install):
 package architecture (amd64) does not match system (arm64)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libmysqlclient-dev_5.6.48-1debian9_amd64.deb
 libmysqlclient18_5.6.48-1debian9_amd64.deb
 libmysqld-dev_5.6.48-1debian9_amd64.deb
 mysql-client_5.6.48-1debian9_amd64.deb
 mysql-common_5.6.48-1debian9_amd64.deb
 mysql-community-bench_5.6.48-1debian9_amd64.deb
 mysql-community-client_5.6.48-1debian9_amd64.deb
 mysql-community-server_5.6.48-1debian9_amd64.deb
 mysql-community-source_5.6.48-1debian9_amd64.deb
 mysql-community-test_5.6.48-1debian9_amd64.deb
 mysql-server_5.6.48-1debian9_amd64.deb
 mysql-testsuite_5.6.48-1debian9_amd64.deb
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can we run amd64 architecture on a raspberry pi 4?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1210404/how-can-we-run-amd64-architecture-on-a-raspberry-pi-4)

Comment: *amd64* is the architecture created by AMD that is x86 compatible, and is used by AMD & INTEL cpus.  ARM64 & ARMv7/armhf are for ARM holdings cpus, and are not compatible having their own instruction set (used by raspberry pi, most android phones etc), so you cannot use the amd64 binaries. You can grab source, and compile for the desired cpu, or find & use pre-built  *arm64* binaries.

Comment: No, this answer doesn't solve the problem that I can't install MySQL 5.6

Answer (score 0):

MySQL 5.6 is available for the Raspberry Pi via `stretch`, but they’re pretty big. Take a look at [buildd.raspbian.org](http://buildd.raspbian.org/status/logs.php?pkg=mysql-5.6&arch=armhf) and grab a build that might work for you.

Alternatively, there’s MariaDB, which is generally seen as a drop-in replacement for the 5.x run of MySQL.