# Incompatibility of chip architecture?

Tags: virtualbox, dependencies

Whenever i try to install virtualbox on my Ubuntu machine (arm), it gives me errors like-

```
Virtualbox-6.1:amd64 depends on zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4).
 virtualbox-6.1:amd64 depends on python (<< 2.8).
 virtualbox-6.1:amd64 depends on python (>= 2.7).
 virtualbox-6.1:amd64 depends on python:any (>= 2.6.6-7~).
```

And i think it is because of architecture incompatibility.

I am a relatively new linux user and unable to install most amd64 files, what should i do?

Comment: You are correct. `amd64` packages cannot be installed on an ARM system. Not too many ARM devices are capable of running a VM, either. Which CPU are you using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can we run amd64 architecture on a raspberry pi 4?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1210404/how-can-we-run-amd64-architecture-on-a-raspberry-pi-4)

Answer (score 3):

Virtualbox is a virtualization tool for x86 and AMD64 platforms, and will not run on ARM.

From [first Google search result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ow24D.png):

> VirtualBox is a powerful x86 and AMD64/Intel64 virtualization product for enterprise as well as home use.

See [[NotSupported] aarch64](https://web.archive.org/web/20210305225615/https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=92857) on Virtualbox forums for reference.

Comment: Can you perhaps quote from there what specifically states that it's an x86 platform tool and not an ARM tool?  As it stands this is a Link only answer and if the forum post goes away then your answer becomes a non-answer.

Comment: the link is already going to a 404 :+)

Comment: 404ing link means that this is a link only answer and will not survive much longer on site.  Please either update the link, or provide other support and evidence to support your statement.

Comment: @Rinzwind i have the impression that virtualbox.org is down at the moment

Comment: @ThomasWard I beg to differ. The answer is stated in the (admittedly short) answer. The link should have provided documentation for what I am saying(so that the OP does not have to rely on my words, but on the one's of the developers...)

Comment: I took the liberty of adding a screenshot of a Google search as reference, since this cites the website directly, now that it's currently down.

Comment: Wayback machine to the rescue (cc @Rinzwind) :)